# Linked list sorting function in C++ doesn't stop properly

Tags: c++, sorting, linked-list

Many thanks in advance!
So, I've made attempts to make this function work. There are mistakes in the function but cannot catch them.
It seems to me, that I've missed the logic of sorting.
Could you point me 'where to go'?

```
  /* node*/
typedef struct client {
    int number; /* */
    int balance;/* */
    char lastName[20]; /* */
    char firstName [20];/* */
    char phone[11]; /* */
    char email[20];
    struct client *prev;/* */
    struct client *next; 
    struct client *tmp;     /* */

} Client;
Client *firstc,*currentc,*newc, *a, *b,*tmp;  /*pointers*/
/* *"firstc' firstc element in list
   *'currentc' current node 
   *'newc' new node
   *'a' temporary pointer to Sort function
   *'b' temporary pointer to Sort function
   *'tmp' temporary pointer to Sort function
*/
int counter = 0;
int cnum = 0; /*cnum gives unique account numbers avoiding misentering*/

/*---Sort function------*/  

void Sort()
{
/* */
int a = 0;/*variables to store balance*/
int b = 0;/*variables to store balance*/
if(firstc==NULL)
     printf("Database is empty"); /*message*/

else 
    currentc = firstc;
    currentc->prev = NULL;
    tmp = NULL;

while((currentc=currentc->next)!= NULL)
    {   /* 1) compare two nodes;
           2) IF balance >*/
        int a = currentc->balance;
        int b = currentc->next->balance;/* debugger stopped here... */                      

        if (a>b)
        //if(currentc->balance >currentc->next->balance)
        {   /*swap nodes*/

        /*code using three pointers*/
        tmp = currentc->next;
        currentc->next->next = currentc->next;
        currentc->next->next = tmp;

        }
        /*3)move along the list*/
        else
            currentc = currentc->next;

        /*4) repeat to the end of list*/
    }   
    currentc = firstc;
    listAll();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you missing curly braces around the code in the first `if/else` block? Your indentation seems to imply those three lines of `else` code belong together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int b = currentc->next->balance;/* debugger stopped here... */
```

When `currentc` is pointing to the last item in the list `currentc->next` will be null. So  `currentc->next->balance` is an access through a null pointer.

Also, practices like making assignments in conditions like `while((currentc=currentc->next)!= NULL)` will eventually come back to hurt you. In this case it seems you are skipping the first item in the list.

You probably meant:

```
if(firstc == NULL)
    printf("Database is empty"); /*message*/
else 
{  /*  missing braces spotted by others */
    currentc = firstc;
    currentc->prev = NULL;
    tmp = NULL;


    for( ; currentc != NULL; currentc = currentc->next)
    {  
        if(currentc->next == NUL)
            /* nothing to compare */
            break;
        ...
    }
}
```

Furthermore the swapping code is swapping the wrong nodes:

```
    tmp = currentc->next;
    currentc->next->next = currentc->next;
    currentc->next->next = tmp;
```

will almost (but not quite) swap the next node (b),  with the one after it instead of with (a). You need to use the `prev` pointer (However since this looks like homework I had better not tell you exactly how to do it). Also, you are initialising `prev` but you need to keep it up to date in the loop. Actually, your 3 lines above are equivalent to:

```
    tmp = currentc->next;
    currentc->next->next = tmp;
```

so I think you meant something else.

Comment: Logic, logic and once more logic. Papier und stift first.

Comment: @Mariner I am just curious why you just *unaccepted* this answer, then accepted the other one when this one identifed the same problem as the other one but was first, plus my answer found many other problems in your code. Is there something wrong with my answer?

Comment: Really sorry about that! Just a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is when currentc is the last node,  currectc->next is null, thus currentc->next->balance make it crash.

add some validation like
`if (currentc->next == null)`

and set b to a default/predefined value or put some logic whether you swap the nodes or not.

Comment: That was the reason to ask 'where'. Debugger opened the list of connected nodes wth <Bad ptr> and empty fields of the last node.

Comment: Looking through this segment of code I  can see three group of mistakes:1) lack of algorythmical logic while planning programm; 2)syntax mistake(s); 3)program wasn't revised on paper when stopped unexpectedly. Suppose keeping in mind all the programm is not a choice now. Special thanks to senior members to usefull and interesting comments!